# Как создать слайдер с градиентом в unity?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! Пытаюсь сделать слайдер, который должен уменьшаться в размерах. Также там невидимый handler и когда он доходит до нуля, получается вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли это как-то исправить и если да, то как?